# What is algo of Adaptive History Based Shceduler?

Tags: algorithm, memory, scheduling

I know AHB schedule according to multiple histories to fetch required data but how this algo does this. Please Explain.

Answer (score 0):

AHB schedulers are mainly built upon a finite state machine. Finite state machine model let to put some weight (cost) on each transition (data, instruction,...). Transitions weights are updated dynamically at runtime during instruction execution. The scheduler has to decide which next transition to take among possible transitions. The transition can also be probabilistically chosen.